# Generate report by code C# on Dynamics 365

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I am using Dynamics CRM 365 online V9. For order, On approval, I want the system to generate a PDF of an order report, attach the PDF and email it to the Customer.

Do you know how If there is a way to generate the report by code C# on a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

**Update: The below only works with on-premise CRM**

You can generate the report using the ReportService2010 class:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010?view=sqlserver-2016

Then create a new email record and an ActivityMimeAttachment to attach the report to your email. Finally use a SendEmailRequest to send the email.

```
var result = reportExecutionService.Render(...)
var attachment = new ActivityMimeAttachment
{
    Body = Convert.ToBase64String(result),
    ...
};
```

Comment: Do you know if I can use this class from a plugin in dynamics 365 Online ? If yes, how we can call report server in online context ?

Comment: Good question, I wasn't considering your online requirement. After reading up a bit further I believe this approach only works on-prem.